# Cron Expression once each 2 days

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I need to create a cron expression that fires at a specific time every two days. So, for instance today is 26th of November. If I deploy my web app today and the scheduler should start the 28th the 30th the 2nd of december and so on...

Any help?

Thanks,

Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
0 0 12 1/2 * ? *
```

Schedules

```
 1.     Wednesday, November 27, 2013 12:00 PM
 2.     Friday, November 29, 2013 12:00 PM
 3.     Sunday, December 1, 2013 12:00 PM
 4.     Tuesday, December 3, 2013 12:00 PM
 5.     Thursday, December 5, 2013 12:00 PM
```

For Ref: [cronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com)

Comment: That is not correct:
0 0 0 1/2 * ? * (calculating on 09.10.2017) will be executing on Tuesday, October 31, 2017 12:00 AM AND THEN ON Wednesday, November 1, 2017 12:00 AM

Answer (score -2):

Quartz cookbook contains the [How-To: Trigger That Executes Every 2 Days](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/BiDailyTrigger)